# Golden Dict problem with Android 12?

Tags: applications, dictionary, moon-reader

I have Golden Dict lite ver 1.6.6 installed on a Denver tablet (Android 8) working fine, but when I tried on a new tablet (Lenovo M9), it just stopped whenever I tried to use it, since this dictionary is not under development any longer, there's no way for me to get a newer verion.
problem: Golden dict and Moon Reader are installed on my device, whenever I tried to use Goldendict within Moon Reader, it pop-up then a message came up saying that the dictionary stopped working, then quit the app.

Comment: Hi, please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If an app doesn't work on a newer Android version and the app is no longer maintained there is only one thing yo can do: uninstall it. The app was developed for about Android 6 and between 6 and 12 a lot of fundamental changes have been introduced to Android that require changes on code level within an app.